# MultiPattern for DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories

Tags: c#, string, linq, directoryinfo

I would be able to find directories from a direcotryInfo array responding multiples pattern.
I would like to found  all the folder name  = "cli_*" or = "fou_*"

I code this :

```
string searchPattern = "cli_*,fou_*";

foreach (DirectoryInfo Dir in dInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s=>searchPattern.Contains(s.ToString().ToLower())))
{
.....
}
```

But i don't return any directory.

Any ideas please ?

Is the solution ?

```
            foreach (DirectoryInfo Dir in dInfo.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Match regexOne = Regex.Match(Dir.Name, "cli_*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Match regexTwo = Regex.Match(Dir.Name, "fou_*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                if (!(regexOne.Success) && !(regexTwo.Success))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You cannot search for multiple directories by separating the search pattern with a comma.  You will either need to call GetDirectories() twice with two search patterns, or get all the directories and write your own code to filter the directories.

Comment: ok, thanks, is the right solution i edited ?

Comment: Don't post the solution in the question.  Instead, post it as an answer.  It is okay to answer your own question on StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: Also: Try your code.  An asterisk won't work in a Regex.  You might want something like Dir.Name.StartsWith("cli_")